# Craft Commerce Delete Customers

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

Is there a way to delete the users that were created in the customers section?

I made a site and generated multiple accounts for testing purposes, but now I have to deliver it and I don't want those users to show up.

Craft users are successfully deleted, but customers are not.

[image: Craft Commerce Customers]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a console command to kick off a garbage collection run. This will remove any customers not associated with a user or cart/order. It will do other things too.

docs for craft 3x https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/gc.html